# word pattern without regex

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

> "Given a pattern and a string input - find if the string follows the
>   same pattern and return true or false."
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. Pattern : "abba", input: "redbluebluered" should return 1.
> 2. Pattern: "aaaa", input: "asdasdasdasd" should return 1.
> 3. Pattern: "aabb", input: "xyzabcxzyabc" should return 0.

I can think of using regular expression but we needed to do this without regular expression. What is the brute-force approach to do this without regular expression and is there anything more efficient?

If yes can someone explain me in detailed way **brute force vs the efficient way** to solve this problem? This was a pretty difficult question in my opinion.

Comment: Tht's pretty tough question for interview. Is that position requires PhD or above? You can't solve it with regexp anyway.

Comment: (This question is hard to answer *if* you didn't know the length of the substring each symbol of the pattern stands for. More likely than not, an interviewer takes it for granted that each substring is of same length.)

Comment: Here is the tool which solves similar (but more general) problem http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358266/python-find-pattern-in-a-string)

Comment: @flash, is the input size dependent on the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do this recursively.

At each step we have a pattern left to match, the string left to match and the char to string mapping that we already assigned:

```
// initially, map should be empty.  if this method returns true,
// map will contained the successful char-to-string mapping
boolean solve(String ptrn, String str, Map<Character, String> map) {
    // if pattern is empty, string must also be empty
    if (ptrn.length() == 0) {
        return str.length() == 0;
    }

    char c = ptrn.charAt(0);
    if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        // first char of the pattern is alrady assigned
        // the string must begin with the mapped substring
        String substitution = map.get(c);
        if (str.startsWith(substitution)) {
            // chop off the assigned substring and try to match the rest of the string
            return solve(ptrn.substring(1), str.substring(substitution.length()), map);
        } else {
            // the current assignment map is impossible.  fail!
            return false;
        }
    }

    // first char of the pattern is not assigned
    // loop over the string and try assigning substrings
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++) {
        // assign new mapping and try to parse with the new assignment in place
        map.put(c, str.substring(0, i));
        if (solve(ptrn, str, map)) {
            return true;
        }
        // assignment failed.  remove it.
        map.remove(c);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This can, of course, be made more efficient by operating on indexes instead of substrings and by replacing some of the recursion with loops.

Comment: ` i--` shuld be ` i++`?

Comment: @Misha can you help me visualize how this recursive solution is working? I am not able to understand as of now.

Comment: @flash Try to think of it one pattern character at a time.  Suppose the pattern is "aba" and string is "xyzyx".  Go over all possible matches for first 'a'.  For each candidate assignment of 'a', recurse and try to solve for pattern "ba" against whatever is left of the original string after you matched the first 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to check a string if you know the lengths of the substrings corresponding to each pattern character.

The trick to an efficient implementation would seem to be to minimize the number of length assignments you need to check.

For each pattern and test string, there is a linear Diophantine equation that restricts the possible length assignments:

Pattern aaaa with string length 16 ⇒ 4a = 16 ⇒ a=4

Pattern abba with string length 14 ⇒ 2a + 2b = 14 ⇒ a+b = 7

etc.

In most cases the requirement for positive integer lengths will greatly restrict the number of possible length assignments, so my first attempt at this problem would be to enumerate those possible assignments and check each one.

There are still kinds of inputs (lots of pattern letters with long strings) that lead to exponential complexity, however...  but all the other working answers here (currently) have that problem worse.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Based on other answers that I see, my solution is clearly not optimal. While this is incomplete, I think it's worth comparing this to other answers so I'll leave it here.

It seems like this question is intending to find any repeating string of characters within a string of characters. So I think the first task here is to identify which blocks within the strings represent the units of the patterns we're seeking.

In the case of 'redbluebluered', those blocks are 'red' and 'blue'.

```
Set<String> findRepeatedStringsWithinString(String input) {
  Set<String> setOfStrings = new HashSet<String>();
  List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < input.length() - i; j++) {
      String subString = input.substring(i,j);
      setOfStrings.add(subString);
      listOfStrings.add(subString);
    }
  }
  //At this point, I've got a Set of all unique substrings within the input and a List of all substrings that contains lots of duplicates.
  //I need to remove all of the unique Strings from the Set that don't have repeating values in the List for starters.
  //I'll end up with a Set that I think looks like this:
  // r, e, d, b, l, u, re, bl, ue, ed, red, blu, blue

  setOfStrings = removeAllUniqueStringsInListFromSet(listOfStrings, setOfStrings);

  //I've noticed that each of these units is as large as possible, so any String that is a subString within my Set seems valid to remove. I would confirm this with the interviewer.
  setOfString = removeSubStringsFromSet(setOfStrings);

  //Set = red, blue
  //From here, it's a matter of more String comparisons between this Set and the pattern, but other people are producing higher quality algorithms than mine and it's late. I don't think that continuing on this line of reasoning will get either of us the job, but I'll leave this here for others to compare.
}

Set<String> removeAllUniqueStringsInListFromSet(List<String> listOfStrings, Set<String> setOfStrings) {
Map<String, Integer> mapOfStrings = new HashMap<>();
  for(String possiblyUniqueString : listOfStrings) {
    if(mapOfStrings.get(possiblyUniqueString)) {
      mapOfStrings.put(possiblyUniqueString, mapOfStrings.get(possiblyUniqueString) + 1);
    } else {
      mapOfStrings.put(possiblyUniqueString, 1);
    }
  }
  //With this map of number of occurrences of each String in the List, I can now figure out which Strings are unique and remove them.
  for(String key : mapOfStrings.keySet()) {
    if(mapOfStrings.get(key) == 1) {
      setOfStrings.remove(key);
    }
  }
  return setOfStrings;
}

Set<String> removeSubStringsFromSet(Set<String> setOfStrings) {
  //This is me sucking at dealing with Sets, sorry
  List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>(setOfStrings);
  for(String string : listOfStrings) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++) {
      if(!listOfStrings.get(i).equals(string) && listOfStrings.get(i).contains(string)) {
        setOfString.remove(string);
      }
    }
  }
  return setOfStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(isMatch("abba","redbluebluered" ));
        System.out.println(isMatch("aaaa","asdasdasdasd" ));
        System.out.println(isMatch("aabb","xyzabcxzyabc" ));
    }

    static boolean isMatch(String patternString, String dataString) {
        List pattern = toList(patternString);
        List data = toList(dataString);

        return isMatch(pattern, data, new HashMap<>());
    }

    private static boolean isMatch(List pattern, List data, Map<Character, List> matches) {
        if (data == null) {
            return pattern == null;
        }

        if (matches.containsKey(pattern.c)) {
            List list = matches.get(pattern.c);
            List tmp = data;
            while (list != null) {
                if (tmp == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (list.c != tmp.c) {
                    return false;
                }
                tmp = tmp.next;
                list = list.next;
            }
            return isMatch(pattern.next, tmp, matches);
        }

        List tmp = data;
        List partialMatchHead;
        List partialMatchTail;
        partialMatchHead = new List();
        partialMatchHead.c = tmp.c;
        tmp = tmp.next;
        partialMatchTail = partialMatchHead;
        while (tmp != null) {
            Map<Character, List> map = new HashMap<>(matches);
            map.put(pattern.c, partialMatchHead);
            if (isMatch(pattern.next, tmp, map)) {
                return true;
            }
            partialMatchTail.next = new List();
            partialMatchTail.next.c = tmp.c;
            partialMatchTail = partialMatchTail.next;

            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private static List toList(String string) {
        List head = new List();
        head.c = string.charAt(0);
        List current = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
            List tmp = new List();
            tmp.c = string.charAt(i);
            current.next = tmp;
            current = tmp;
        }
        return head;
    }

    static class List {
        char c;
        List next;
    }
}
```

This solution is equivalent to @Misha solution.

**PS**: There is same question in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358266/python-find-pattern-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. I tried a simple way without recursions.
First I check what letters in the pattern exists. Then I create all substrings of the input. In the third step I create all combinations of pattern-letters and substrings. And at the end I test all those combinations.
Not very efficient, but it works.

```
public static int matches(String pattern, String example) {
    // 1. which pattern-letters exist?
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
        set.add(pattern.substring(i, i + 1));
    }

    // 2. which substrings of example exist?
    Set<String> substrings = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (example.length() - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < example.length(); j++) {
            substrings.add(example.substring(i, j));
        }
    }

    // 3. create all combinations
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : set) {
        List<Map<String, String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String x : substrings) {
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put(s, x);
                l.add(map);
            } else {
                for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
                    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
                    for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
                        map2.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                    }
                    map2.put(s, x);
                    l.add(map2);
                }
            }
        }
        list.addAll(l);
    }

    // 4. try all combinations
    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        String match = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            match += map.get(pattern.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        if (example.equals(match)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as follows:

- consider the first character in the pattern ('a' in the first example)
- as 'a' is unknown so far, hypothetize a length for the pattern 'a' (initially 1, corresponding to "r")
- move to the next character in the pattern ('b')
- as 'b' is unknown so far, hypothetize a length for the pattern 'b' (initially '1', corresponding to "e")
- move to the next character in the pattern ('b')
- as 'b' is already known to be "e", you can compare with the next chunk, "d". Here we have a failure and we need to backtrack to the first occurrence of the pattern 'b', and retry with the next length (2,3, ... until there is no more room).
- if no match was possible for 'b', backtrack to the first occurrence of 'a'.

This process continues until either the string is exhausted, or a match has been found for all patterns.

It can be implemented by a recursive procedure that takes as input

- the current pattern,
- the set of hypothetized patterns and corresponding substrings,
- the tail of the string.

If the current pattern has not been hypothesized yet, form the first hypothesis for this pattern (next character from the string) and continue the search. Take care to record the recursion level at which the hypothesis was made for this pattern.

If the current pattern is already hypothetized, check for a match in the string from the current position. If there is a match, recursively continue the search unless you are at the end of the string and are done.

If there is no match, and this is the first occurrence of this pattern for which an hypothesis has been made (i.e. recursion depth equal to the recorded recursion depth), increase the length to hypothesize again and continue the search.

If there is no match and this is not the first occurrence of this pattern, return the identity of the mismatched pattern. (When performing a recursive call, if the returned value indicates a failure, compare the returned pattern identity to the current one and return it to the caller if different.)

```
'a', 'a'= "r", "edbluebluered"
    'b', 'a'= "r", 'b'= "e", "dbluebluered" => mismatch "e" <-> "d"
    'b', 'a'= "r", 'b'= "ed", "bluebluered" => mismatch "ed" <-> "bl"
    'b', 'a'= "r", 'b'= "edb", "luebluered" => mismatch "edb" <-> "lue"
    ...
'a', 'a'= "re", "dbluebluered"
    'b', 'a'= "re", 'b'= "d", "bluebluered" => mismatch "d" <-> "b"
    'b', 'a'= "re", 'b'= "db", "luebluered" => mismatch "db" <-> "lu"
    ...
'a', 'a'= "red", "bluebluered"
    'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "b", "luebluered" => mismatch "b" <-> "l"
    'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "bl", "uebluered" => mismatch "bl" <-> "ue"
    'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "blu", "ebluered" => mismatch "blu" <-> "ebl"
    'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "blue", "bluered"
        'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "blue", "red"
            'b', 'a'= "red", 'b'= "blue", "" done !
```

The condition "no more room" can be simply implemented by checking the length of the string tail and comparing to the current pattern length, but a better estimate is possible by accumulating the lengths of all hypothetized patterns for all their occurrences in the pattern string. For instance, if we hypothetized 'a'="bl" and 'b'="uer", the pattern string "abba" predicts a length at least 10.