# In Python, how do I return multiple matched sub strings from a string

Tags: python

I have a problem where i need to search for email addresses in a long string.
I need to return all the occurences of matches, and not only one.

I've tried:

```
def email():
    try:
        a = re.search(r'abc.{1,11}@xyz.co.za|def@xyz.co.za',string)
        return a.group(0)   
    except Exception:
        return 1
```

and

```
def email():
    try:
        a = re.search(r'abc.{1,11}@xyz.co.za' or 'def@xyz.co.za',string)
        return a.group(0)   
    except Exception:
        return 1
```

and

```
def email():
    try:
        a = re.search('abc.{1,11}@xyz.co.za',string)
        b = re.search('def@xyz.co.za',string)
        return a.group(0),b.group(0)   
    except Exception:
        return 1
```

as well as other different combinations of this.

From the first script, I receive the first match of email address.
From the second script I receive only one match
From the third script i receive all the matches. My problem is that if one of them doesn't match, it returns 1.

What i would like to see is that it returns all the email addresses that matches, regardless of how many match.

Comment: Can't you just return `a`?

Comment: When I return a, it only matches on the first "match", and it will return <re.Match object; span=(4112, 4130), match ='abc@xyz.co.za'>

Comment: Try `r'(abc.{1,11}@xyz.co.za)|(def@xyz.co.za)'`

Comment: Read the question is related you your concern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358266/python-find-pattern-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
def mailbox():
   try:
        a = re.findall(r'abc.{1,11}@xyz.co.za|def@xyz.co.za',string)
        return set(a)  
    except Exception:
        return 1
```

The only problem is that it it will return set() if i don't match anything